# Вывод древовидной структуры

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli

как мне вывести свою структуру в таком же виде как на картинке, если моя структура под цифрой 1 и моя структура вниз идет на 6 уровней

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это достаточно просто делается.
С точки зрения хранения элементов дерева в базе достаточно добавить поле `parent_id` (или похожее по смыслу) в таблицу элементов дерева

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `tree_elements`
--
CREATE TABLE `tree_elements` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `options` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Индексы таблицы `tree_elements`
--
ALTER TABLE `tree_elements`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `tree_elements_parent_id_foreign` (`parent_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `tree_elements`
--
ALTER TABLE `tree_elements`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `tree_elements`
--
ALTER TABLE `tree_elements`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tree_elements_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `tree_elements` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

Это только структура таблицы, но чтобы вывести структуру, нужно получить эелемент по `id`, а потом рекурсивно получать элементы, по нужному `parent_id`.
Например, получаем эелемент по его `id`: **`SELECT * FROM tree_elements WHERE id = ?`**. Потом получаем массив элементов 1-го уровня вложености, у которых `parent_id` равен `id` искомого элемента (**`SELECT * FROM tree_elements WHERE parent_id = ?`**). Получив список элементов второго уровня, делаем запрос к таблице уже с массивом `id` элементов второго уровня.
Например, циклом прошлись по полученным результатам элементов второго уровня, вытащили id-шники в массив `$ids`. Потом делаем запрос элементов третьего уровня, в который передаем массив айдишников - **`SELECT * FROM tree_elements WHERE id IN (?,?,?)`**.
При обработке результатов обычно создается ассоциативный массив с полем `children`

```
$element = [
  'title' => 'root',
  'children' => [
    [
      'title' => 'child1',
      'children' => [
        [
          'title' => 'child2',
          'children' => []
        ],
      ]
    ],
  ]
]
```

Comment: у одного круга - два реферала(дочки), как мне добавить дочки второго уровня еще 2 реферала?

Comment: вся логика в использовании `parent_id`

Comment: а в parent_id у нас храниться id пользователя?

Comment: то есть если дереео должно начинаться с админа сайта, то в первой записи храним его id или созаем еще поле с сохранением id пользователя, а в паренте пихаем id записи в таблице?

Comment: Еще раз) Хранение данных в виде дерева не является сложным. Каждому элементу таблицы бд достаточно знать лишь `id` своего предка (если он имеется. Не обязательно у элемента (пользователя, категории, пункта меню) должен быть родительский элемент. Тебе сейчас важно всего лишь понять суть этой структуры данных

Comment: то, как должно быть устроено твое дерево знаешь только ты. Но попробуй понять такой распространенный компонент, как меню. Есть корневые элементы меню (у который нет `parent_id`) и есть вложенные элементы. Обрати внимание на то, какую структуру БД я в ответе указал. Там есть **ограничение внешнего ключа** - изучи эту тему. Это ограничение не позволяет указать ничего, кроме значения `id` элемента из текущей таблицы.